# The psql cli and bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, psql

I used to use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#:%7E:text=psql%20is%20a%20terminal%2Dbased,and%20see%20the%20query%20results.) to connect to an aws redshift instance, and I would like to know if I can do the same with bigquery ?

At first sight, it seems like not because, unlike redshift, bigquery is not built on top of postgresql or something similar to it (it is built upon dremel). Is this understanding correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually, we can have a behaviour similar to psql/redhsift with bq/bigquery: we can enter a shell with `bq shell`, once inside this shell, we can write sql commands without prefixing them with `bq query --use_legacy_sql=false` (which we do in a bash shell)

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery is not built on top of PostgreSQL, so you cannot use psql to connect to it directly. However, there are a few ways to connect to BigQuery from psql. One way is to use the BigQuery ODBC driver. Another way is to use the BigQuery Python API.